# Is there a better way to format seconds to mm:ss format in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I am currently formatting seconds to mm:ss format using the code below. Is there a better option?

```
   def formatted_length(length) do
     minutes =
      length/60
      |> Float.floor()
      |> round()
      |> Integer.to_string()

     seconds =
      rem(length, 60)
      |> Integer.to_string()
      |> String.rjust(2, ?0)

     minutes <> ":" <> seconds
   end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is actually incorrect: for `90`, it returns `"2:30"`.

You can use `div` to do integer division which ignores the decimal part. As for the rest, I'd use string interpolation to shorten the code:

```
defmodule Main do
  def formatted_length(length) do
    "#{div(length, 60)}:#{formatted_seconds(rem(length, 60))}"
  end

  defp formatted_seconds(s) when s < 10, do: "0#{s}"
  defp formatted_seconds(s), do: "#{s}"
end

13 |> Main.formatted_length |> IO.puts
123 |> Main.formatted_length |> IO.puts
143 |> Main.formatted_length |> IO.puts
```

Output:

```
0:13
2:03
2:23
```